# RichTextBox Highlighting

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, highlight

### Goal

Programmatically **highlight** part of a string contained in a RichTextBox based on what is selected in a DataGridView.

*See screenshot for a more visual example*
[image: Selected Option Type Highlights it's related options]

As you can see, when an Option type (EC - Electrical) is selected, its options are displayed in another DataGridView to the right. From there, the user can check the ones he wishes to have included in the Conveyor Function Summary (Photoeye in this case) and it gets highlighted.

---

### Code Used

This method is executed every time the Option Type DataGridView has a selectionchanged event.

```
Private Sub SummaryOptionsHighlight()
    Dim strToFind As String = ""
    Dim textEnd As Integer = rtbSummary.TextLength
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim lastIndex As Integer = 0

    'Builds the string to find based on custom classes - works fine
    For Each o As clsConveyorFunctionOptions In lst_Options
        If o.Included Then
            If strToFind.Length <> 0 Then strToFind += ", "

            If o.Optn.IsMultipleQty And o.Qty > 0 Then
                strToFind += o.Optn.Description & " (" & o.Qty & "x)"
            Else
                strToFind += o.Optn.Description
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Retrieves the last index of the found string: ex. Photoeye (3x)
    lastIndex = rtbSummary.Text.LastIndexOf(strToFind)

    'Find and set the selection back color of the RichTextBox
    While index < lastIndex
        rtbSummary.Find(strToFind, index, textEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        rtbSummary.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight
        index = rtbSummary.Text.IndexOf(strToFind, index) + 1
    End While
End Sub
```

---

### Problem

What's going on isn't a **highlight** but more of a backcolor being set to that selection. The reason I say this is because when I click in the RichTextBox to indicate that it has focus, it doesn't clear the highlighting. Perhaps there is an actual **highlight** instead of a backcolor selection?

***See the difference:***

Selection Back Color: [image: SelectionBackColor]

Highlighting: [image: Manual Highlight]

Comment: Just add `rtbSummary.SelectionColor = SystemColors.HighlightText` after your SelectionBackColor property.  Focus is a different issue.  It's unclear what should happen to those highlighted items.

Comment: @LarsTech For the highlighted items when I focus on the RichTextBox, they should go back to their original colors. Your comment helped me find my solution. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

to highlight, you just need to do this:

```
if richtextbox1.text.contians("photoeye") then
richtextbox1.select("photoeye")
end if
```

this should work for what you are trying to do

Comment: -1. There is no such overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.select(v=vs.110).aspx) that can pick a string value.

Comment: try when you change your backcolor, change the textcolor to white and make backcolor to light blue